# Как можно вставить union в структуру?

Tags: c, gcc, типы-данных, struct, union

Мне нужна структура в которой будут следующие данные:

```
typedef struct {
float   data[32];
int     size;
} Mcalc;
```

Но данные 'float   data[32];' мне нужно представить в виде старших 2 байт int16_t float и младших 2 байт uint16_t float. Просто старшие два байта float пишутся в int16_t младшие два байта в uint16_t. Преобразование типа float ---> uint16_t не нужно.

Попытался сделать вот так:

```
typedef union {
    struct{
        int16_t  data_i[32];
        uint16_t data_ui[32];
    };
    float data_f[32];
} unionIntFloat; // Здесь пытался сделать объединение.
```

Но как можно заменить `float   data[32];` на `unionIntFloat` не понял.

Хочу что-то типа:

```
typedef struct {
unionIntFloat
int     size;
} Mcalc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы этого добиваетесь?

```
typedef union {
    float f;
    struct {
        unsigned short int lo, hi;
    };
} unionFloat;

typedef struct {
    unionFloat   data[32];
    int     size;
} Mcalc;
```

Comment: А как теперь обратиться к lo, hi ?

Comment: @zhilenkov создать объект типа unionFloat; ```unionFloat ufl; unsigned short int lo = ufl.lo;``` ну или конкретно из кода выше: создаете ```Mcalc calc;``` далее ```calc.data``` и есть массив с вашими юнионами

Comment: Только не хватает информации о том что безымянные структуры были добавлены в с11, или же являются gnu c extensions.

Comment: @SelfishCrawler пишу calc.data[0].f - получаю ошибку.

Comment: @zhilenkov [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/hCySewK.png) нет ошибок, используйте компилятор поновее

Comment: Да все правильно )).

Comment: Ну вот, смотрите: https://ideone.com/HEOdLv